# Angular2 & jQuery Datatables - Issue with using Angular 2 Components inside render function for column definition

Tags: angular, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables plugin inside an Angular 2 project, and I'm facing the following issue when using Angular 2 custom components inside the template string returned from render function. Here is code snippet:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'my-custom-grid',
    templateUrl: './my-custom-grid.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-custom-grid.less'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class MyCustomGridComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {}

    dataGridConfig:any = {
        "paging": false,
        "info": false,
        "destroy": true,
        "columns": [
        {
            data: 'customerName',
            title: 'CUSTOMER NAME',
            render: function(data, type){
                return "<span *ngIf='someBoolean'>Welcome Text</span><my-
                    new-component></my-new-component>";
            }
        }
        ],
        "fixedHeader": true,
        "scrollX": true,
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "dom": 't',
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        "responsive": false
    };
}
```

The problem is that `*ngIf` and `<my-new-component></my-new-component>` are not being compiled by Angular 2 when I use them inside the render function above.

Why does this happen? Is there any way to use Angular 2/4 custom components and structural directive inside render function of jQuery DataTables?

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this ?